# How to split chessboard into tensors so that they can be analyzed as a batch

Tags: performance, machine-learning, pytorch

I am currently trying to process a chessboard with a machine learning model by splitting the image into 64 squares, and then getting the model prediction from each square. However, I was wondering if there is any way I can somehow split the original image into groups so that they can be analyzed simultaneously as a batch so the code can run much faster.

Here is my current code:

```
squares = image_processing('/Users/Me/Downloads/Screen Shot 2022-07-04 at 11.09.04 AM.png')
image_transforms = transforms.Compose([  
                    transforms.ToTensor()])

board = []
for square in squares:
    square = Image.fromarray(square)
    square = image_transforms(square).float()
    square = square.unsqueeze(0)

    output = model(square)
    _, predicted = torch.max(output.data, 1)
    board.append(classes[predicted.item()])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could divide your input into chunks on the horizontal and vertical axes by alternating between [`torch.Tensor.chunk`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.chunk.html) and [`torch.cat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cat.html), then recompose the image after it has been fed to the model.

Here is a minimal setup involving a batch of input images `(1, 3, 128, 128)` which will be splitter into a total of *64* patches:

```
>>> in_img = torch.rand(1, 3, 8*16, 8*16)
>>> PATCH_SIZE = 16
>>> size = in_img.size(2)//PATCH_SIZE
```

We first create chunks of the images in the batch:

```
>>> patches = cat([cat(p.chunk(size, dim=-2)) for p in in_img.chunk(size, dim=-1)])
```

The shape of this tensor will be `(1, 3, 16, 16)`. Then perform inference on your model:

```
>>> out = model(patches)
```

And reconstruct the image by assembling all the chunks on both axes:

```
>>> out_img = cat(cat(out.split(8), dim=-1).chunk(8), dim=-2)
```

The final output shape will be `(1, c, h, w)`.

---

Overall the performed operation will:

1. Take the input image of shape `(b, c, h*n_patches, w*n_patches)`.
2. Transform it into a tensor of patches shaped `(b*n_patches*n_patches, c, h, w)`.
3. Apply inference to get a new tensor of shape `(b*n_patches*n_patches, c', h', w')`.
4. Finally reassemble the image into `(b, c', h'*n_patches, w'*n_patches)`.

Comment: When I tried running your code, I got the following error: ```RuntimeError: chunk expects `chunks` to be greater than 0, got: 0```

Comment: Could you provide the shapes of the intermediate tensors you are getting?

Comment: The size of my tensor is ```torch.Size([345, 345, 3])```.

Comment: You should permute and reshape your data to fit the use case described above such that it has a shape of `(1, 3, 345, 345)`.

Comment: I just reshaped it and got this error instead: ```RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 0. Expected size 17 but got size 5 for tensor number 20 in the list.```

Comment: You should do: `x = x.permute(2, 1, 0).unsqueeze(0)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246150/discussion-between-ozzy08-and-ivan).